# What is the meaning of "argv['A']" in c?

Tags: c

I have found the following code, and I do not understand what it is or how it works. I have only seen `argv[n]` (argv with an integer index) in C before, never with a character literal like `argv['A']`.

```
if(argc != 100) return 0;
if(strcmp(argv['A'],"\x00")) return 0;
if(strcmp(argv['B'],"\x20\x0a\x0d")) return 0;
printf("Stage 1 clear!\n");
```

What does this do? Could you explain why it works?

Comment: `'A'` is a number, try `printf("%d\n", 'A');`.

Comment: Assuming [ASCII encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII), `'A'` is equal to the integer value `65`.

Comment: Where have you read this apalling piece of code?

Comment: Variables looks like parameters of the main function. Is the code sample really from the main function?

Comment: If this is from `main` I would like to see how to provide those 2 parameters via command line...

Comment: The actual encoding for string literals is the one you tell or let the compiler use. (/fexecution-charset or -fexec-charset) The users would also need to know what that is in many programs (where they are providing text input that has to match or have to understand text output).

Comment: For any future people seeing this. This is a challenge from pwnable.kr called 'input'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Technically, this is valid in C for accessing an element of the argv (`argv[65]`).

**Edit**: as John Ballinger noted in the comments, this is only if your C implementation maps character literals to their ASCII values, which is not required by the standard. However, most C implementations do, so I would assume the author of the code was using this assumption.

This is because in C, all character literals can act as numeric literals.

Granted, if you are expecting 65+ elements in your argv, something is probably wrong. And even so, using `'A'` and `'B'` for the indices 65 and 66 wouldn't make sense unless you had some specific association of your argv with letters.

**TL;DR** it is an index, but the code is incredibly abnormal and probably intentionally obfuscated

Comment: *Technically*, it is implementation-dependent which `argv` element is accessed.  Implementations are not required to use ASCII to map characters to integers, and some don't.

Comment: "all character literals can act as numeric literals". Character literals have type `int` anyway.

Comment: @Gerhardh. Yes, but a lot of people forget that chars are an integral numeric type. So I was just being explicit with that.

Answer (score 2):

`'A'` is just a way of specifying a value with an `int` type (which, given that you've passed an alphanumeric character, must be capable of fitting into a `char` on your platform.) The value is implementation defined, although in ASCII, it's 65.

So `argv['A']` is rather like `int n = 'A'; argv[n];`

Whether or not the program is equipped with that many command line arguments (`argc` will tell you that and `if(argc != 100)` is an insufficient check) is another matter.

That all said, it's possible to call `main` from itself in C; perhaps the command line arguments are introduced then, as an exercise in obfuscation.